When do forces result in oscillation of oscillator?
I recently learned about the Cavendish experiment, which is used to find the Gravitational constant $G$. In short, two masses $m$ are put on the opposite sides of a balanced metal bar which hangs from the ceiling on a thread. By later positioning a greater mass besides each of the masses $m$, the metal bar will rotate a small amount in response because of the "gravitational force".
See it here (The big masses are manually rotated towards the small ones, which rotate on their own, "after" the manual rotation has been finished):

During the lecture I was surprised to find the bar with the small masses oscillating back and forth after the initial pull towards the big masses (because of the thread getting twined up).
I asked the lecturer if such an oscillation would always occur, since I presumed (and imagined in my head) that the gravitational force by the big masses was so small, that the bar with the masses would stop near them (in the equilibrium of the gravitational force and the force of the thread).
They gave a prolonged answer on the "yes".
I was expecting a more nuanced answer, where oscillation would only occur in specific cases, dependent on the intensity of the two forces and their change over time.
When I make an analogy with a pendulum, where the pendulum experiences, after switching a flip a gravitational force from the side as well, I could imagine the pendulum just being displaced by a certain amount in direction of the new force, without oscillation (Or will the amplitude of the oscillation just be so small that you cant see it?).
Is there indeed always an oscillation (in an idealized system)? What would be the keywords for me to look into this?
